# Find and Replace LIke Value in mySQL data

Tags: mysql

I have a column called `meta_key` and has values like `wp_10_s2_cat33` and `wp_10_s2_cat44` etc. I'd like to find `wp_2` and replace it with something like `wp_10`. How can I do something like that in a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [REPLACE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function performs a string replacement.

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET meta_key = REPLACE(meta_key, 'wp_2_', 'wp_10_')
WHERE meta_key LIKE 'wp\_2\_%';
```